# Jquery get input value inside list which is inside a div

Tags: jquery

I have something like the following

```
<div id="container">
      <ul id="name_list">
          <li class="name">
             <input type="hidden" class="name_val" value="5" />
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the value of the input. So far I have the following Jquery statment.

```
$("#container li.name input.name_val").val();
```

this does not work anyone know a better way?

Comment: don't be unnecessarily specific, $('container').find('input').val()  or even just $('.name_val').val() should do the job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were having a typo in your input class name

```
$("#container li.name input.name_val").val();
```

Also you can change your selector to something like

```
$("#name_list > li.name > input:hidden.name_val").val();
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part, this does not work for me should it?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 3):

Give your `<input>` either a name or an id.  The you can get the value in either of these two ways:

```
$('input[name=thename]').val()
```

or

```
$('input#theid').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Should it be

```
var value = $('input.name_val').val();
```

You don't need to mention the other parts of the dom, just the area you are interested in.